# Are there any VIP Services at Nicaragua airport?

Tags: airports, nicaragua

At the Augusto C. Sandino International Airport (the airport in Managua, Nicaragua), I have heard there is a VIP service you can pay for, where an agent will meet you when disembarking from the plane and guide you through the immigration and customs process, or somehow make it easier. I emailed but the address is not longer in service for one of them.  Do you have any idea for an active VIP Service there?

Answer (score 2):

AssisTant (no affiliation) offers this service as mentioned on [their website](https://assist-ant.com/fast-track-airport-vip-service/):

> To have a smooth and worry-free airport arrival experience, be sure to register with our fast-track airport VIP services. As soon as your plane lands, you will be met by one of our courteous agents at your gate. He/she will then drive you in a private vehicle to passport control.
>
> There we will go through all procedures for arrival via a VIP counter. We will assist you with passport control, collect your baggage, and assist you with customs. If you’ve arranged for one of our drivers to pick you up from the airport, we’ll personally escort you to the driver who will take you quickly anywhere and everywhere you need to go.

[This](https://assist-ant.com/airport-vip-services/mga-managua-nicaragua/) is the companies website, specifically for Augusto C. Sandino International Airport in Managua, Nicaragua.